# Elevation in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, administrator, runas

***Backstory***

I have a script that calls Enable-Mailbox right after creating a new user's account but the problem is I need to pass admin credentials along with the command in order for it to work.  The script was made with a GUI to ease the process of daily admin tasks and will be used by people who don't know anything about PowerShell or even how to change directory to where the script is.  Because of this I want it to run when double clicked in explorer and prompt the user once for admin credentials.  Once the credentials are entered they will be stored in a file in the same directory using the following code:

```
Try {
    $credsFile = Import-Clixml "credentials"
    $credsFile.Password = $credsFile.Password | ConvertTo-SecureString
    $adminCreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential($credsFile.Username, $credsFile.Password)
}
Catch {
    # This means the credentials file does not exist
    $adminCreds = Get-Credential
    $adminCreds = $adminCreds | Select-Object *
    $adminCreds.password = $adminCreds.Password | ConvertFrom-SecureString
    $adminCreds | Export-Clixml "credentials"
    $adminCreds.password = $adminCreds.Password | ConvertTo-SecureString
}
```

***Attempts***

Since Enable-Mailbox does not have a -Credential parameter for me to pass to it I've been trying to find a way to run the script as an administrator from the start with the stored credentials.  I created a script that attempts to call the main script in an elevated state.

The first one I tried was:

```
Start-Process -File "$PSHOME\powershell.exe" -ArgumentList "-NoExit","-Command Scripts\MainScript.ps1" -Credential $adminCreds -Wait
```

but it simply prompts for credentials (every time) and never loads the script.

Next I tried:

```
start-process powershell -verb runas -argument "scripts\MainConsole.ps1"
```

This loads the script just find from within the ISE but doesn't load it when doubled clicked in explorer.

I've also looked into Invoke-Command and Invoke-Expression to try and run the Enable-Mailbox command as an admin but have not been successful.  Does anyone know how to either run the script as an admin from the start or at least pass credentials to Enable-Mailbox and other parameters like it?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're not running this script on the Mail server, you could authenticate using your Exchange admin credentials when this connection is called?
Something like:

```
$server = "exchangeserver.domain.local"

Import-PSSession (New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://$server/PowerShell -Authentication Kerberos -Credential $Credential)
Enable-Mailbox -Identity $cn -Alias $user
```

I would personally advise against storing the creds in a file, but you should be able to run this as any user, and pass credentials to the $credential variable as above (or just let them log in each time).

If they need additional help with remembering correct usernames, etc, I quite like assisting with stuff like this (depending on how your accounts are named):

```
$credential = Get-Credential "exchange_admin" # or
$credential = Get-Credential $env:Username"_admin"
```

On the subject of running from an icon, one horrendous workaround that I'm aware of is to create a batch file that runs

```
@powershell -FilePath \\fullpath\to\script.ps1 -params
```